# Warning error when export to excel (HTML to Excel) using table2excel.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I'm exporting to Excel (HTML or Excel) using table2excel.js getting below error.

"The file you are trying to open, '[filename]', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"  (Yes | No | Help)

```
function exportToExcel(){
    $('#row').table2excel({
        exclude: ".noExl",
        name: "SearchDetails",
        filename: "SearchDetails"
    });
}
```

/* 
  *  jQuery table2excel - v1.0.2 
  *  jQuery plugin to export an .xls file in browser from an HTML table 
  *  https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel 
  * 
  *  Made by rainabba 
  *  Under MIT License 
  */ 
 //table2excel.js

;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) { 
     var pluginName = "table2excel",

```
 defaults = { 
     exclude: ".noExl", 
             name: "Table2Excel" 
 }; 


 // The actual plugin constructor 
 function Plugin ( element, options ) { 
         this.element = element; 
         // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or 
         // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object 
         // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for 
         // future instances of the plugin 
         // 
         this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options ); 
         this._defaults = defaults; 
         this._name = pluginName; 
         this.init(); 
 } 


 Plugin.prototype = { 
     init: function () { 
         var e = this; 


        var utf8Heading = "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8\">"; 
         e.template = { 
            head: "<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">" + utf8Heading + "<head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets>", 
             sheet: { 
                 head: "<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>", 
                 tail: "</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>" 
             }, 
             mid: "</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body>", 
             table: { 
                 head: "<table>", 
                 tail: "</table>" 
             }, 
             foot: "</body></html>" 
         }; 


         e.tableRows = []; 


         // get contents of table except for exclude 
         $(e.element).each( function(i,o) { 
             var tempRows = ""; 
             $(o).find("tr").not(e.settings.exclude).each(function (i, o) {
                 var cloneRow = $(o).clone();
                 $(cloneRow).find(e.settings.exclude).remove();
                 var html = $(cloneRow).html();
                 tempRows += "<tr>" + html + "</tr>";
                 }); 
            /* $(o).find("tr").not(e.settings.exclude).each(function (i,o) { 
                 tempRows += "<tr>" + $(o).html() + "</tr>"; 
             }); */
             e.tableRows.push(tempRows); 
         }); 


         e.tableToExcel(e.tableRows, e.settings.name, e.settings.sheetName); 
     }, 


     tableToExcel: function (table, name, sheetName) { 
         var e = this, fullTemplate="", i, link, a; 

         e.uri = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,"; 
         e.base64 = function (s) { 
             return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); 
         }; 
         e.format = function (s, c) { 
             return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { 
                 return c[p]; 
             }); 
         }; 


         sheetName = typeof sheetName === "undefined" ? "Sheet" : sheetName; 


         e.ctx = { 
             worksheet: name || "Worksheet", 
             table: table, 
             sheetName: sheetName, 
         }; 


         fullTemplate= e.template.head; 


         if ( $.isArray(table) ) { 
             for (i in table) { 
                   //fullTemplate += e.template.sheet.head + "{worksheet" + i + "}" + e.template.sheet.tail; 
                   fullTemplate += e.template.sheet.head + sheetName + i + e.template.sheet.tail; 
             } 
         } 


         fullTemplate += e.template.mid; 


         if ( $.isArray(table) ) { 
             for (i in table) { 
                 fullTemplate += e.template.table.head + "{table" + i + "}" + e.template.table.tail; 
             } 
         } 

         fullTemplate += e.template.foot; 


         for (i in table) { 
             e.ctx["table" + i] = table[i]; 
         } 
         delete e.ctx.table; 


         if (typeof msie !== "undefined" && msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer 
         { 
             if (typeof Blob !== "undefined") { 
                 //use blobs if we can 
                 fullTemplate = e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx);
                 fullTemplate = [fullTemplate]; 
                 //convert to array 
                 var blob1 = new Blob(fullTemplate, { type: "text/html" }); 
                 window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob1, getFileName(e.settings) ); 
             } else { 
                 //otherwise use the iframe and save 
                 //requires a blank iframe on page called txtArea1 
                 txtArea1.document.open("text/html", "replace"); 
                 txtArea1.document.write(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx)); 
                 txtArea1.document.close(); 
                 txtArea1.focus(); 
                 sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, getFileName(e.settings) ); 
             } 


         } else { 
             link = e.uri + e.base64(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx)); 
             a = document.createElement("a"); 
             a.download = getFileName(e.settings); 
             a.href = link; 


             document.body.appendChild(a); 


             a.click(); 


             document.body.removeChild(a); 
         } 


         return true; 
     } 
 }; 


 function getFileName(settings) { 
    return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel" ) + 
           ( settings.fileext ? settings.fileext : ".xls" ); 
 } 


 $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) { 
     var e = this; 
         e.each(function() { 
             if ( !$.data( e, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) { 
                 $.data( e, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) ); 
             } 
         }); 

     // chain jQuery functions 
     return e; 
 };
```

})( jQuery, window, document );

Comment: Can you provide any code?

Comment: function exportToExcel() {
  
  $('#row').table2excel({
    exclude: ".noExl",
    name: "SearchDetails",
    filename: "SearchDetails"
   
   });
  }

Comment: Please provide the code and/or error messages as an **edit** to your question.

Comment: Updated my code in question. Do you need table2excel.js code also?